# Trigonometry identity $\csc x\cot x=\frac{\cos ^3x}{\sin^2 x}+\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove that $\csc x\cot x=\frac{\cos ^3x}{\sin^2 x}+\cos x$?

I tried manupulating the left hand side but ended up in $\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}$.

Can someone show me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So far, so good. Now look at the RHS. It's equal to $\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}$. But why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$RHS = \dfrac{\cos^3 x}{\sin^2 x}+ \cos x=\dfrac{\cos^3 x+\cos x \sin^2x}{\sin^2 x}=\dfrac{\cos x (\sin^2x+\cos^2 x)}{\sin^2 x}=\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin^2x}$ BECAUSE 
$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x =1$...

Now, $\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin^2x}=\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x} \dfrac{1}{\sin x}=\cot x \csc x.$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\cos ^3x}{\sin^2 x}+\cos x$$
$$\cos x\left(\cot^2x+1\right)=\cos x\left(\csc^2x\right)= \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\left(\csc\right)=\cot x \csc x$$

Comment: How $\cos x(\csc^2 x)$ becomes $\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}(\csc x)$ ?

Comment: @Mathxx $\csc x=\frac{1}{\sin x}$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\csc x\cot x-\cos x=\cos x\left(\dfrac1{\cos^2x}-1\right)$$

$$\dfrac1{\cos^2x}-1=\dfrac{1-\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}=\dfrac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice, we have to prove $$\csc x\cot x=\frac{\cos^3x}{\sin^2x}+\cos x$$ Taking RHS as follows $$RHS=\frac{\cos^3x}{\sin^2x}+\cos x$$ $$=\cos x\left(\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right)^2+\cos x$$ $$=\cos x\cot^2x+\cos x$$ $$=\cos x(1+\cot^2x)$$ $$=\cos x(\csc^2x)$$ $$=\csc x\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$$$=\csc x\cot x=\color{blue}{LHS}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\csc(x)\cot(x)=\frac{\cos^3(x)}{\sin^2(x)}+\cos(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\csc(x)\cot(x)=\frac{\cos^3(x)+\cos(x)\sin^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\csc(x)\cot(x)\sin^2(x)=\cos^3(x)+\cos(x)\sin^2(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\cdot\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\cdot\sin^2(x)=\cos^3(x)+\cos(x)\sin^2(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(x)=\cos^3(x)+\cos(x)\sin^2(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(x)=\cos(x)(\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x))\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$1=\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$1=1$$

The left hand side and right hand side are identical -> identity has been verified